# How Add To Cart product without reloading page by using Ajax in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: ajax

That's my controller code
public function add_cart(Request $request , $id)
{

```
    // Validate the request if needed
    if (Auth::guard('customer')->check()) {

    $product = Product::find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Product not found'], 404);
    }
    $product = Product::find($id);
      $user = Auth::guard('customer')->user();
      $add_cart = new Cart;
      $add_cart->product_id = $product->id;
      $add_cart->user_id = $user->id;
      $add_cart->quantity = $request->quantity;
      $add_cart->save();
   
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Product added to cart']);

  }

  else {
    return view('auth.customer_login');
  }
```

{"message":"Product added to cart"}
This message is show after adding product butt i just want to see add same page with new product add

Comment: The code you've shared looks like PHP, not like JS code. What's your question about this? Also, keep in mind that Laravel 5.6 is EOL since years

Answer (score 0):

Please add condition check its a ajax request.

```
public function add_cart(Request $request , $id) {

    // Validate the request if needed
    if (Auth::guard('customer')->check()&& $request->ajax()) {

    $product = Product::find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Product not found'], 404);
    }
    $product = Product::find($id);
      $user = Auth::guard('customer')->user();
      $add_cart = new Cart;
      $add_cart->product_id = $product->id;
      $add_cart->user_id = $user->id;
      $add_cart->quantity = $request->quantity;
      $add_cart->save();
   
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Product added to cart']);

  }

  else {
    return view('auth.customer_login');
  }
}
```

add route

app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::get('/add_cart/{id}','AjaxController@add_cart');
```

Now our View

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Ajax Example</title>
      
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      
      <script>
         function add_cart() {
            $.ajax({
               type:'get',
               url:'/add_cart/' +id,
               data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
               success:function(data) {
                  $("#msg").html(data.message);
               }
            });
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body>
<div id="msg"></div>
      <div id = 'product'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
         Click the button to replace the message.</div>
      <?php
         echo Form::button('add To Cart',['onClick'=>'add_cart()']);
      ?>
   </body>

</html>
```